# Why do I get "SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200" message in my iOS application's output in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a fairly simple Xamarin Forms app (basically started with an example and added background audio) and for the last couple of hours I'm getting the following messages on the Application Output console:

```
2021-02-17 18:51:57.791376+0100 sample.iOS[4789:73550] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=4789
2021-02-17 18:51:57.791617+0100 sample.iOS[4789:73550] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: sample.iOS[4789]/0#-1 LF=0
2021-02-17 18:51:57.796796+0100 sample.iOS[4789:73550] SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=4789
2021-02-17 18:51:57.797030+0100 sample.iOS[4789:73550] SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: sample.iOS[4789]/0#-1 LF=0
```

I've already tried the following:

- Reinstalled Visual Studio for Mac
- Cleaned and rebuilt my project
- Restarted my Mac
- Restarted the simulator
- Deleted and reinstalled the app from the Simulator

Still can't get rid of the messages. iPhone 12 Simulator with latest iOS (14.4)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Hi, you could have a look at this dicussion: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/237465/what-means-sectaskloadentlitlements-failed-error-22 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/173801/sectaskloadentitlements-failed-error22-cs-flags200.html

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT - I actually saw both of them but none of them answers the problem :( The one at learn.microsoft.com is literally unsolved, the one on apple.stackexchange.com explains that it should not happen but doesn't address why does it happen of what is the possible resolution.

Comment: @adamsfamily Did you manage to work it out? I'm stuck with the exact same problem.

Comment: @Beltway Unfortunately no :( I don't think that Microsoft would fix any non-critical bugs in Xamarin Forms as they've clearly declared their intention to shut it down :( The good news is that these messages seem to be harmless. Not ideal though..

Comment: @adamsfamily I suspected it to be critical at first, turns out it really is not.